# Google Analytics don't show any stats on Angular site

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I have code like this:

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', bmb.vars('ga')['trackingId'], {
    'cookieDomain': 'none'
});
ga('set', 'appVersion', bmb.version());
```

I have cookieDomain because I'm testing this on localhost

and in Angular:

```js
bmb.site.$module.config(function ($analyticsProvider) {

    $analyticsProvider.virtualPageviews(false);
    $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(false);
    $analyticsProvider.registerPageTrack(function (page, title) {
        if (title) {
            page = {page: page, title: title}
        }
        if (window._gaq) _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', page.page || page]);
        if (window.ga) ga('send', 'pageview', {page: page.page || page});
    });
});
```

I don't know from where that registerPageTrack came from but it's executed on every url (hash) change in router.

When I run this code I don't get any stats in google analytics site, what's wrong with that code?

Comment: Are you using angular-google-analytics?